# django admin changes not reflecting on pythonanywhere free server

Tags: django, python-3.6

I have created an app "mybook" using django 1.11 and python 3.6 on pythonanywhere.com free server.
Url of app is `http://suryavsics07.pythonanywhere.com/`, issue is that none of changes are reflecting on admin. I have created `customer`model

Directory structure is as bellow:

`moneybook
    media/
    moneybook/
        __init__.py
        __init__.pyc
        settings.py
        settings.pyc
        urls.py
        urls.pyc
        wsgi.py
    mymoney/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    static/
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py`

I run `python3 manage.py check` and 0 error found. Where i am wrong?

Code in `model.py` file:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Customer(models.Model):
    cust_id = models.IntegerField("Customer Id",unique=True,db_index=True)
    cust_name = models.CharField("Name",max_length=200,null=True)
    cust_email = models.EmailField("Email Id",max_length=200,unique=True,default='NULL',null=True,)
    cust_mobile = models.CharField( "Mobile No.",max_length=15,null=True)
    cust_pin = models.IntegerField("PIN",blank=True)
    cust_created_date = models.DateField("Registration Date",auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    """String for representing the Model object."""
    return self.cust_name
```

Comment: Have you registered the model in your admin? Make sure you restarted the server after making changes to your code.

Comment: yes, i have registered model in admin...

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair i restarted server and got changes in admin. it works